# Check for a float value

Tags: ios, swift

I am doing a small game where if your score 34 it means you get 3 times 2 which equal to 6 and if you score 36 it means you get 4 * 2 = 8 but if you get 35 then it will be the same just 3.5 * 2 = 7

here is a small code that I was able to check if you got 6 and above or 4 and below but not the 5 which I am having a hard time to solve

```
// example:
// player score 35 he will get 7 because 3.5 * 2 = 7
// player score 37 he will get 8 because 4 * 2 = 8
// player score 32 he will get 6 because 3 * 2 = 6



var newScore = Double(score)
newScore = newScore / 10
newScore = round(newScore)
newScore = newScore * 2

// I am not sure how to check if the user gets 35 or 45 
// first I have to convert it to float so it will be 3.5 or 4.5
// then check if it has the .5 otherwise the round function will round it to 4 or 5 instead of * it by 2
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There may be other ways , but for your cases you can do

```
var newScore = Double(score) 
newScore = newScore / 10 
if score % 10 != 5 {  
    newScore = round(newScore)  
} 
print(newScore) 
print(newScore * 2)
```